# Database indexes: A good thing, a bad thing, or a waste of time?

Tags: sql, database-design, cross-platform

Adding indexes is often suggested here as a remedy for performance problems.

(I'm talking about reading & querying ONLY, we all know indexes can make writing slower).

I have tried this remedy many times, over many years, both on DB2 and MSSQL, and the result were invariably disappointing.

My finding has been that no matter how 'obvious' it was that an index would make things better, it turned out that the query optimiser was smarter, and my cleverly-chosen index almost always made things worse.

I should point out that my experiences relate mostly to small tables (<100'000 rows).

Can anyone provide some down-to-earth guidelines on choices for indexing?

The correct answer would be a list of recommendations something like:

- Never/always index a table with less than/more than NNNN records
- Never/always consider indexes on multi-field keys
- Never/always use clustered indexes
- Never/always use more than NNN indexes on a single table
- Never/always add an index when [some magic condition I'm dying to learn about]

Ideally, the answer will give some instructive examples.

Comment: It all depends on the speed of your disks, and the size of your memory, and so on.

Comment: First of all, edit your question!  **Adding** indices can only make a query faster, never slower.  What you mean to be asking is about specifying that the query optimizer **USE** an index, in effect overriding what it would do on it's own... That can potentially make a query slower

Comment: @Charles Bretana: Adding an index CAN make a query slower if it causes the optmiser to choose a bad plan or if it adversely affects the use of other indexes. Also adding an index will generally slow down inserts/updates/deletes.

Comment: EDIT to correct earlier comment above. "First of all, edit your question! Adding indices ***generally*** only makes a query faster. It will only ***_very rarely_*** make it slower. What you mean to be asking is about specifying that the query optimizer USE an index, in effect overriding what it would do on it's own... That can potentially make a query slower."

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Indexes are kind of like chemotherapy...too much and it kills you...too little and you die...do it the wrong way and you die.  You gotta know just how much, how often, and what kind to make it not kill you.

Your hardware, platform, environment, load all play a role.  So to answer your questions..

Yes, possibly sometimes.

Comment: Love the chemo analogy (sorry, Charlie Villanueva), but you should add "no matter what happens, you're going to feel very sick".

Comment: +1 Indeed, lovely analogy, and probably closer to reality than most of us would like

Comment: Do you really think you answered the question? "It depends" - doesn't answer anything at all.

Comment: @ArtemNovikov well, the proff of the pudding is in the eating.  have you done much dba work?  if so, go right ahead and list the "always/never" things you're supposed to always/never do.  My thought is you haven't.

Answer (score 12):

As a rule of thumb, primary keys and foreign keys need to be indexed. Usually primary key are indexed just by defining them as such, but FKs are not in every database (they definitely are not in SQL Server, I can't really speak for other dbs). You will be using these in joins, so it is generally critical to performance to define these.

Now if you have fields you often use in where clauses, they can benefit from indexes as well providing several things:

- First the field must have a range of
  values. A bit field or a field with
  only 2 or 3 values will almost never
  use an index.
- Second the queries you write must be sargable. That is they must be designed to use indexes. I suspect if you never get performance improvements from what look like likely candidates for indexes, then you probably have queries that are not sargable. For instance take "WHERE Name like '%Smith'" as a where clause. Without knowing the first characters, the optimizer can't use the index.

Small tables rarely benefit much from indexes. If the optimizer can hold the whole thing in memory, then it is often faster to do so. If you were working with multimillion record tables, you would see that indexes are critical.

Indexing can be very complex and if you are interested in the subject, I suggest you get a good book on performance tuning your particular database and read in depth about them.

Answer (score 5):

An index that's never used is a waste of disk space, as well as adding to the insert/update/delete time.  It's probably best to define the clustering index first, then define 
additional indexes as you find yourself writing `WHERE` clauses.

One common index mistake I see is people wondering why a select on col2 (or col3) takes so long when the index is defined as `col1 ASC, col2 ASC, col3 ASC`.  When you have a multiple column index, your `WHERE` clause must use the first column in the index, or the first and second column in the index, and so forth.

If you need to access the data by col2, then you need an additional index that's defined as `col2 ASC`.

With small domain tables, it's sometimes faster to do a table scan than it is to read rows from the table using an index.  This depends on the speed of your database machine and the speed of the network.

Answer (score 3):

You need indexes. Only with indexes you can access data fast enough.

To make it as short as possible:

- add indexes for columns you are frequently filtering (or grouping) for. (eg. a state or name)
- `like` and sql functions could make the DBMS not use indexes.
- add indexes only on columns which have many different values (eg. no boolean fields)
- It is common to add indexes to foreign keys, but it is not always needed.
- don't add indexes in very short tables
- never add indexes when you don't know how they should enhance performance.

Finally: look into execution plans to decide how to optimize queries.

You'll add indexes just for a single, critical query. In this case, you'll add exactly the indexes that are needed in the query in question (multi-column indexes).

Answer (score 2):

```
Always use clustered indexes.
```

In fact you can't help but using them. The data in a table will be laid out on disk in some particular order anyway, it can't be save as a pile or something. You have the chance of specifying how exactly this data will be laid out. Why burn it?

When you have a table which gets new records appended and you observe that some value in those records always grow (like StackOverflow question number), make a clustered index out of it. Then the new data will not be inserted in the middle but will basically be appended to a file on disk which is a relatively cheap operation.

Answer (score 2):

Basically when DB is collecting data and it's alive indexes have to go and evolve with that flow. There maybe really good index on table but after growing beyond of XXX records the same index in the same table is useless and in that case it should be refactored.

To have optimized and fast DB the only way is to monitor it all the time and refactor it over the time as records come in.

Real life example i got some time ago was super fast query restricted by some time range (created_at between A and B) and super slow query where time range was different. Same query, same database, same application and only one difference on time range.

Comment: +1 different key ranges=different performance, good point. How does one analyse/fix this?

Answer (score 1):

If a table is expected to be the target of a join then it is best to have a clustered index on that table so that the joins can be performed sequentially through the data pages. The columns in the clustered index will (on some DB systems) be included in all of the other indexes on that table, since those are the values that the indexes will use to reference the table data. To keep the other indexes from getting too large, the columns in the clustered index should be as narrow as possible, so it is best to use only numeric—rather than character—data types in the clustered index. In general, fewer columns are better than more columns, but notice that three `int` columns (12 bytes per row) are much better than one `nvarchar(32)` column (potentially 64 bytes per row).

If the clustered index is narrow, then a few additional indexes should not negatively impact performance very much even on very large tables.

Answer (score 0):

Seems you are confusing two concepts here. 
Adding indices ****generally*** <strike>*can*</strike> only make a read query faster, very very rarely (almost never)  slower.  Adding an index never forces the query optimizer to use it. It will only use it if it thinks it can benefit from it, and it is generally very smart about those decisions.

For inserts/updates, of course, every index hurts performance a bit more... But at the other end of the spectrum, for, say a read only database, (like a USPS address database which is distributed monthly), in operational use there would ne no inserts/updates, so the only negative impact of additional indices is the disk space they take up.

This is entirely different that *specifying* that the query optimizer USE an index, in effect overriding what it would do on it's own...   That can potentially make a query slower.

EDIT: Edited to eliminate opportunity for misinterpretation by overly literal readers.

Comment: @Charles Bretana: "can only make a query faster, never slower" I disagree _completely_ and that's precisely the point I'm making; adding an index changes the way the query optimiser makes its plan (an index is considered as a strong hint). I have observed (and timed) the same query, which becomes considerably slower when an index is added. And please refrain from suggesting what I should be asking; the phrasing of the question should make it clear that I know what I'm looking for, thanks.

Comment: @smirkingman, the edge cases where what you describe happens are so rare as to not be worth investing any significant effort into. And the phrasing of your question does indicate that you do not understand index technology. to wit, "... index would make things better, it turned out that the query optimiser was smarter, and my cleverly-chosen index almost always made things worse." This statemen, cannot be literally true, except in very rare and unusual circumstances (Unless you override the optimizer). If it were true, it implies that the rest of the entire database industry are all idiots.

Comment: @Charles Bretana I'm sorry, but they are not edge cases. _Your_ experience might be that indexes always make things better, mine is not, and it's precisely this myth which I'm questioning. My question is all the more valid when I note that the answers so far lack any objective justification except gut feeling and/or rote learning. Oh and BTW, I've been working with DBMSs since the early 1990's and I've probably spent more evenings poring over query plans than you've had hot dinners; so instead of being derogatory, backup your answers with something more concrete than what you read in a book.

Comment: @Charles Bretana: Adding an index CAN make a query slower if it causes the optmiser to choose a bad plan or if it adversely affects the use of other indexes. Also adding an index will generally slow down inserts/updates/deletes. I agree with skirkingman, these are not edge cases. A poorly chosen index is often worse than no index at all.

Comment: Unles you consciously override the optimizer, the only way a new index can adversely affect the performance of a query is if the optimizer chooses to use it, This is why these **ARE** edge cases! So, how to define "Edge"? - clearly something that happens **most** of the time (what was implied) is **NOT** an edge case). Without attempting to specify exactly how often the optimizer guesses correctly, I know that it guesses correctly often enough that characterizing the cases where it does not, as "edge" is not a mis-characterization. Characterizing it as "almost always made things worse" **IS**

Comment: @Dportas, yes of course it affects inserts and updates, (and deletes too btw), but we are explicitly talking about selects here...

Comment: @Charles Bretana You apparently have an unquestionable belief that "indexes always improve performance" and on that basis, you state that my observations cannot possibly be true (implying that I'm a troll), and you're apparently ready to argue this _ad nauseum_. Were your premise to be correct, the logical conclusion is that one should index every queryable field in a database. My belief, demonstrated here, is that debate with bigots is fruitless, so I think it best that we simply agree to differ.

Comment: @dportas: thank you, nice to hear from someone with an open mind  "Choose a bad plan"

Comment: @smirk, No, read my posts more carefully, don't attempt to straw man the argument... YOU are the one making the [almost] absolute argument. We are discussing your position, not mine. I NEVER said "indexes always improve performance", YOU said they "almost always made things worse", which is what I am calling into question.

Comment: @Charles Bretana : Then it must have been an imposter who said this? "Adding indices can only make a query faster, never slower" That was the false statement I objected to.

Comment: @Charles Bretana  I would be grateful if you could refrain from adding anything further to this thread. Thank you. @dportas please don't feed the troll

Comment: @dportas, The rest of that sentence, says " ... very very rarely (almost never) slower." If this entire thread is based on an inability to extract meaning from a complete sentence, when the first half doesn't agree with you, then I confess to being astounded.  But, to address this albiet insignificant distinction, I will edit that sentence to remove all opportunity for mischaracterization or misunderstanding.

Comment: @smirk, As to my propensity to "argue this ad nauseum", well, I will plead guilty to that. I enjoy arguing, actually. Even, on occasion, (not this time), when I have to take a position I disagree with. I will take it from your last post you are not similarly inclined. As you obviously do not feel any similar reluctance to enter into the arguments in the first place, however, you should try harder to stay focused on the substance of the argument, (or at least make sure you are clear about what it is) and not the personality or character of the people involved.

Comment: @Charles: I was referring to your first comment, on the original question. Not the answer you are quoting now. It unequivocally says "never slower" and does not have the "very rarely" comment at all. Please reread what you wrote. I think that still deserved correcting for the benefit of anyone who might be mislead by it.

Comment: @dportas.. You are correct, I missed that in our discussion. and you are also correct in that it overstates the argument (although my whole reason for making it in the first place is based on the intent, not on the literal interpretation, and I would posit that that intent was made clear in the response we are herein commenting on). However, you are still correct, and, since I can no longer edit the comment, and deleting it would obfuscate this discussion for future readers, so i will add another comment correcting the mistake.