# MongoDB uses filter before IXSCAN although compound index exists

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

this is my schema:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b726f066f8400317d55b9d7"),
    "question" : ObjectId("5b726bf66f8400317d54ea79"),
    "variableCollections" : [ 
        {
            "variableId" : ObjectId("5b726d746f8400317d553e9c"),
            "variableCollectionId" : ObjectId("5b726d2e6f8400317d54feda")
        }
    ]
}
```

this is the index of the schema

```
{
    "question" : 1,
    "variableCollections.variableCollectionId" : 1,
    "variableCollections.variableId" : 1
}
```

When I try the following query even with or without hint. winningPlan always do a $eq filter before IXSCAN but it should have directly use the IXSCAN right away without filter.

```
db.getCollection('questionAnswers').find({ 
        question: ObjectId('5b726bf66f8400317d54ea79'), 
        'variableCollections.variableId': ObjectId("5b726d746f8400317d553e9c"),
        'variableCollections.variableCollectionId':ObjectId("5b726d2e6f8400317d54feda")
    })
    .hint("test1")
    .explain({"verbosity":"allPlansExecution"})
```

The winningPlan is as follows

```
{
    "stage" : "FETCH",
    "filter" : {
        "variableCollections.variableId" : {
            "$eq" : ObjectId("5b726d746f8400317d553e9c")
        }
    },
    "inputStage" : {
        "stage" : "IXSCAN",
        "keyPattern" : {
            "question" : 1,
            "variableCollections.variableCollectionId" : 1,
            "variableCollections.variableId" : 1
        },
        "indexName" : "test1",
        "isMultiKey" : true,
        "multiKeyPaths" : {
            "question" : [],
            "variableCollections.variableCollectionId" : [ 
                "variableCollections"
            ],
            "variableCollections.variableId" : [ 
                "variableCollections"
            ]
        },
        "isUnique" : false,
        "isSparse" : false,
        "isPartial" : false,
        "indexVersion" : 2,
        "direction" : "forward",
        "indexBounds" : {
            "question" : [ 
                "[ObjectId('5b726bf66f8400317d54ea79'), ObjectId('5b726bf66f8400317d54ea79')]"
            ],
            "variableCollections.variableCollectionId" : [ 
                "[ObjectId('5b726d2e6f8400317d54feda'), ObjectId('5b726d2e6f8400317d54feda')]"
            ],
            "variableCollections.variableId" : [ 
                "[MinKey, MaxKey]"
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

How can I force mongo to use IXSCAN without using $eq in filter to improve the performance of this query? or this is already the best performance I can get?

Answer (score 0):

As per my knowledge for the find operation, MongoDB always use $eq operation internally. So I think you have the best query plan. But don't use many indexes as your query result might get slow.

Comment: Indexes are nothing but the physical copy(replica) of your whole collection. If document size is more then many indexes may increase your database memory on physical drive.  [Read this.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4267928/database-indexes-a-good-thing-a-bad-thing-or-a-waste-of-time)